# Convergence of $1 - {1 \over 2} + {1 \over 2} - {1 \over 2^2} + {1 \over 3} - {1 \over 2^3} + {1 \over 4} - {1 \over 2^4} + \cdots$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Determine whether $$1 - {1 \over 2} + {1 \over 2} - {1 \over 2^2} + {1 \over 3} - {1 \over 2^3} + {1 \over 4} - {1 \over 2^4} + \cdots$$ converges or diverges.

I'm having a little difficulty showing whether the above alternating series converges or diverges. Initially, I thought that I could rewrite the series to be $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left({1 \over n} + {(-1)^{2n-1} \over 2^n}\right)$, however I don't know this to be true since there aren't parentheses presented in the original series. I then attempted to determine if the series is telescoping, but it is not entirely evident within the first few terms up to $n=6$.

Can anyone provide a hint as to how I can determine whether or not the series converges or diverges?

Comment: You can write the sum as $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(\dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{1}{2^n})$.

Comment: If $a_n$ is the $n$-th term of your sequence, it is not difficult to show that $$\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n = \log(N)+O(1),$$ hence the series is divergent.

Comment: @MaliMish, I do apologize for this question, but how do I necessarily know that this is true? What is the difference between *that* expression and $$1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + \cdots = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (1 + (-1)^{2n-1})?$$

Comment: @pyrazolam Notice that $2n-1$ is odd number so $(-1)^{2n-1}=-1$ for all $n$. Thus, you can remove power $2n-1$. In any case, $-1$ and $(-1)^{2n-1}$ have same value.

Comment: @MaliMish, I know from one exercise in my textbook that if $\sum a_n$ converges, then inserting parenthesis wherever means that the resulting series will also converge to the same limit. However, I suppose my main question is, will add parentheses wherever to a *divergent* series mean that it also diverges? The book does not comment on the latter--only on *removing* parentheses.

Comment: 1-1+1-1... is an example of divergent series that becomes convergent if we insert parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a_n=\dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{1}{2^n}$. Using limit comparison test with $b_n=\dfrac{1}{n}$ gives limit 1. Hence, given series diverges because $\sum \dfrac{1}{n}$ diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_n$ denote the $n$th partial sum of the series. Then

$$S_{2n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k} - \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2^k} > \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k} - 1.$$

Because $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k} \to \infty,$ we see $S_{2n} \to \infty,$ hence the sequence $S_n$ diverges, which implies the given series diverges.

Answer (score 1):

The negative terms converge, the positive terms don't. So their sum doesn't.